# unity inverted mask image doesn't work after async loading scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I load a scene async, masked UI element is not visible. After disabling and re-enabling the object the element is visible correctly.

Why is the class not working after loading the scene async?

Here is my image class for inverted mask.

```
public class CutOutImage : Image
{
    public override Material materialForRendering
    {
        get
        {
            var _material = new Material(base.materialForRendering);
            _material.SetInt("_StencilComp", (int)CompareFunction.NotEqual);
            return _material;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with the inverted mask, and found [this thread in Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-inverse-mask.342324/), so I tried what styrbo suggested. But didn't work initially, then I tried changing maskable to false and back to true in the Fix Coroutine, and it worked!
So, this is what I added to the CutoutMaskUI class:

```
protected override void Start()
{
    base.Start();
    StartCoroutine(Fix());
}

/// Fix for async loading scenes
private IEnumerator Fix()
{
    yield return null;
    maskable = false;
    maskable = true;
}
```